# Streaming compressed responses

Tags: python, json, flask, gzip

I have a flask endpoint that returns a stream of json objects and want to make it stream compressed responses. My code basically works but the compressed responses **sometimes** break streaming and generally seem slower. Does anyone know how to make it stream?

#### Flask endpoint returns

```py
if compress:
    def compress_manually_gzip(json_str) -> bytes:
        return gzip.compress(json_str.encode())
    json_wrapped_results = map(
        lambda r: compress_manually_gzip(json.dumps(r) + "\n"), results
    )
else:
    # Appending a newline to json to make it easier for the client to process the stream.
    json_wrapped_results = map(lambda r: json.dumps(r) + "\n", results)

resp = Response(json_wrapped_results)
resp.headers["gzipped"] = get_args().compress_response
return resp
```

#### Caller:

```py
    resp: requests.Response = requests.put(
        url,
        headers=headers,
        data=bytes_to_send,
        verify=verify,
        stream=True,
        timeout=timeout,
    )
    if resp.headers.get("gzipped", False) == "True":
        # maybe this line is buffering too much input
        for line in gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=resp.raw): 
            chunk = json.loads(line)
            yield chunk, timer() - t0, resp.headers
    else:
        for line in resp.iter_lines():
            yield json.loads(line), timer() - t0, resp.headers
```

When I say breaks streaming, it means the chunks for compressed response don't come in evenly spaced

received times compressed: [1.03, 1.7, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2]  (all bunched at end)

uncompressed: [0.99, 1.2, 1.8, 2.4, 3.2]